# Aiogram. Отправка сообщения в определенную тему супергруппы Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Переписал бота с telebot на aiogram (2.14.2), по большей части у меня всего три обработчика разных команд, по которым бот должен ответить. Бот позиционируется как для использования одним пользователем, так и для работы в группах. Если с первым все окей, то по второму возникает вопрос. Как отправить сообщение в ту же тему супергруппы telegram, из которой его запустили (кроме способа с message.reply)?
В telebot для этого используется message_thread_id, он указывается в bot.send_message, однако, насколько я понимаю, в aiogram нет такой возможности?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам нужен параметр message_thread_id.

```
bot.send_message({ID Группы}, "lorem", message_thread_id={ID Ветки группы})
```

[Вот документация на метод send_message для Aiogram 2.25.1](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/v2.25.1/telegram/bot.html?highlight=bot%20sendmessage#aiogram.bot.bot.Bot.send_message), там второй параметр сверху

Answer (score 0):

Обновил до 2.25.1 - заработало, в 2.14.2 нет такой возможности, по всей видимости